# trouble with parseing JSON with ASPJSON for classic ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

I am using ASP JSON at http://www.aspjson.com/

I am trying to parse the salehistory the out of this JSON response below. I can get all the nodes under the property object like this

oJSON.data("property").item(0).item("vintage").item("lastModified")

However when I try to go deeper I get errors

I have tried

oJSON.data("property").item(0).item("salehistory").item("salesearchdate") but that does not return anything.

I think that it has something to do with the fact that property is an object and SalesHistory is an object inside of Property however I cannot seem to get the values out of the salehistory level.

Below is the JSON structure that I am trying to parse. Any help would be appreciated. .

```
{
"status": {
"version": "1.0.0",
"code": 0,
"msg": "SuccessWithResult",
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"pagesize": 10
},
"property": [
{
"identifier": {
"obPropId": 3464768712115,
"fips": "12115",
"apn": "0283080001",
"apnOrig": "0283080001"
},
"lot": {
"lotSize1": 0.837
},
"address": {
"country": "US",
"countrySubd": "FL",
"line1": "7580 PRESERVATION DR",
"line2": "SARASOTA, FL 34241",
"locality": "Sarasota",
"matchCode": "ExaStr",
"oneLine": "7580 PRESERVATION DR, SARASOTA, FL 34241",
"postal1": "34241",
"postal2": "5201",
"postal3": "R038"
},
"location": {
"accuracy": "Street",
"elevation": 0,
"latitude": "27.267342",
"longitude": "-82.419812",
"distance": 0,
"geoid": "MT30003379,RS0000548079,SD67554,SS156496,SS156498,SS190868"
},
"summary": {
"propclass": "Single Family Residence / Townhouse",
"propsubtype": "SINGLE FAMILY",
"proptype": "SFR",
"yearbuilt": 2005,
"propLandUse": "SFR"
},
"building": {
"size": {
"universalsize": 4256
},
"rooms": {
"bathstotal": 5,
"beds": 4
}
},
"vintage": {
"lastModified": "2015-9-11",
"pubDate": "2015-10-7"
},
"salehistory": [
{
"salesearchdate": "2009-3-30",
"saleTransDate": "2009-3-30",
"amount": {
"saleamt": 1250000,
"salerecdate": "2009-3-30",
"saledisclosuretype": 0,
"saledocnum": "37737",
"saletranstype": "Resale"
},
"calculation": {
"priceperbed": 312500,
"pricepersizeunit": 294
}
},
{
"salesearchdate": "2005-8-9",
"saleTransDate": "2005-8-9",
"amount": {
"saleamt": 185000,
"salerecdate": "2005-8-15",
"saledisclosuretype": 0,
"saledocnum": "181999",
"saletranstype": "Resale"
},
"calculation": {
"priceperbed": 46250,
"pricepersizeunit": 43
}
}
]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was able to get it figured out.

Since it was a nested object within the property object I need to do the following to access it.

response.write oJSON.data("property").item(0).item("salehistory").item(0).item("amount").item("saleamt"

Adding .item(0) after sales history allowed me to access the salehistory object